# Making the field with empty JSON array if there is no data on joined table in PostgresQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I having this query:

```
SELECT 
  establishment.*,
  JSON_AGG(
    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
      'id', esi.id,
      'url', esi.url,
      'itemType', esi.item_type
    )
  ) logos
FROM establishment
LEFT JOIN establishment_storage_item AS esi ON establishment.id = esi.establishment_id
GROUP BY establishment.id;
```

It returns establishments with field logos as a JSON array of objects.

The problem that I have, that if there is no logo for some establishment, the array will have one object with nulable fields. What I need is ab empty array instead.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, I found two possible solution for it.

**Solution one**, with the same query, add the COALESCE:

```
SELECT 
  establishment.*,
  COALESCE(
    JSON_AGG(
      JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(
        'id', esi.id,
        'url', esi.url,
        'itemType', esi.item_type
      )
    ) FILTER (WHERE esi.id IS NOT NULL),
    '[]'
  ) logos
FROM establishment
LEFT JOIN establishment_storage_item AS esi ON establishment.id = esi.establishment_id
GROUP BY establishment.id;
```

**Solution two**, and maybe more elegant one, is to use subquery instead:

```
SELECT
  establishment.*,
  COALESCE(
    (
      SELECT
        JSON_AGG(ROW_TO_JSON(esi_data))
      FROM (
        SELECT
          esi.id,
          esi.url,
          esi.item_type AS "itemType"
        FROM establishment_storage_item AS esi
        WHERE establishment.id = esi.establishment_id
      ) esi_data
    ),
    '[]'
  ) logos
FROM establishment;
```